# How can I make request with callback?

Tags: reactjs, callback, request

First of all I have a function on (Utils.js) to make requests.

```
static Request(data, callback) {

        const method = data[0] || "";
        const url = data[1] || "";
        const param = data[2] || "";
        const headers = data[3] || "";

        if (method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
            data = {
                url: url,
                method: method.toLowerCase(),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    param
                }
            };

            if (headers) {
                data.headers = {
                    headers
                };
            }

            axios(data).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        } else if (method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {
            axios.get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data);
                    callback(response.data);
                    return (response.data);
                })
        } else {
            console.log("Undefined");
        }
    }
```

Then I have a component called Table.js (that is using my own things and React-table)

And I have a Page.js to make the request and send props to Table.js

```
componentDidMount() {
        Utils.Request(['get', 'URL'],
            (data) => {
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                var projects = this.state.retrieveProjects.concat([data]);
                this.setState({ retrieveProjects: projects })
                this.retrieveTableProjects();
            })

        this.retrieveTableProjects = () => {
            this.state.retrieveProjects.map((item) => {
                const modifiedData =
                    [
                        {
                            col1: item.data.title,
                            col2: "" + item.data.newMentions,
                            col3: item.data.createdDate,
                            col4: item.data.createdBy,
                        }
                    ]
                this.setState({ dataTable: modifiedData })
            })
        }
    }
```

Then in Page.js I want to use that information dataTable from state.

```
<Tables dataRows={this.props.dataTable} test="Teste" />
```

The thing is.. the `dataTable` is not displayed. In Table.js I can access prop **test** but can't access prop **dataRows**, it returns undefined. So.. I need to work with callback right? What solutions can I apply here?

Thanks.

EDIT1:

dataTable returns an array.

```
[{
col1: "lorem"
col2: "lorem"
col3: "lorem"
col4: "lorem"
}]
```

Comment: in ```console.log(this.props.dataTable)''' whats result?

Comment: I edited, go check. Its a simple array. @A.R.SEIF

Comment: are you use [react-table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table)?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my post.

Comment: ok.suggest for you.put code in https://codesandbox.io/